# How to create RedisCacheManager in spring-data 2.0.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, jedis

I'm migrating my application from spring boot 1.5.x to 2.0.x. I want to keep jedis but I have a problem with the instantiation of `RedisCacheManager`.

Now constructor signature is

```
RedisCacheManager(RedisCacheWriter cacheWriter, RedisCacheConfiguration defaultCacheConfiguration)
```

But before it was:

```
RedisCacheManager(RedisOperations redisOperations)
```

I define this bean having only `RedisTemplate` in scope:

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    HandleRedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new HandleRedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    return redisCacheManager;
}
```

How is it supposed to be created now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't accept a RedisTemplate anymore. So try this:

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory,
                                      ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder builder = RedisCacheManager
            .builder(redisConnectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(determineConfiguration(resourceLoader.getClassLoader()));
    List<String> cacheNames = this.cacheProperties.getCacheNames();
    if (!cacheNames.isEmpty()) {
        builder.initialCacheNames(new LinkedHashSet<>(cacheNames));
    }
    return builder.build();
}

private org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration determineConfiguration(
        ClassLoader classLoader) {
    if (this.redisCacheConfiguration != null) {
        return this.redisCacheConfiguration;
    }
    CacheProperties.Redis redisProperties = this.cacheProperties.getRedis();
    RedisCacheConfiguration config = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .modulesToInstall( new SimpleModule().addSerializer( new NullValueSerializer(null)) )
            .failOnEmptyBeans( false )
            .build();
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping( ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

    GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer serializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer( mapper );

    //get the mapper b/c they registered some internal modules
    config = config.serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(serializer));;

    if (redisProperties.getTimeToLive() != null) {
        config = config.entryTtl(redisProperties.getTimeToLive());
    }
    if (redisProperties.getKeyPrefix() != null) {
        config = config.prefixKeysWith(redisProperties.getKeyPrefix());
        config = config.computePrefixWith(cacheName -> redisProperties.getKeyPrefix() + cacheName + "::");
    }
    if (!redisProperties.isCacheNullValues()) {
        config = config.disableCachingNullValues();
    }
    if (!redisProperties.isUseKeyPrefix()) {
        config = config.disableKeyPrefix();
    }
    return config;
}
```

Comment: If it stopped accepting `RedisTemplate` as parametr to constructor - does the logic of the code by omitting it changed? Or is the same as it was in SpringBoot 1.5?

Answer (score 20):

try  following code , it works for me on spring-boot 2.1.0.RELEASE

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
    RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(1))
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.json()));
    redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();

   return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory)
                    .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();

}
```

Comment: redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix(); does not make any sense. It is a method that just returns a boolean. The class is immutable so setUsePrefix needs to have some equivalent in the builder.
It seems as usePrefix defaults to true if not explicitly disabled with RedisCacheConfiguration#disableKeyPrefix()

Comment: @MikaelVandmo The way I read the code, usePrefix defaults to false.  It goes to true if you call .prefixKeysWith(String)  or .computePrefixWith()

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(1))
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.json()));
      redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();
      return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory())
          .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();
}
```

Comment: Hello, please add some details about your answer. E.g. what were our changes, why did you make these changes, etc.